# GCP Health check not working with VM (Cent OS 7)

Tags: load-balancing, firewall, google-compute-engine

I've been running a Compute engine for over a year now without issues. Everything works fine and centos 7 is fully updated. I'm running plesk as hosting software and server is accessible over http and https.

I just setup a Health check in GCP with the following settings:

- **name**: healtcheckname
- **In use by**: servername
- **Path**: /
- **Protocol**: HTTPS
- **Port**: 443
- **Interval**: 5 seconds
- **Timeout**: 5 seconds
- **Unhealthy threshold**: 2 consecutive failures
- **Healthy threshold**: 2 consecutive successes

However it seems to return a 0 not successful. This limits me on using a load balancer with GCE and I was wondering if someone can offer some help. I already added the following firewall rule:

- **Network**: default
- **Source IP ranges**
  130.211.0.0/22 and 35.191.0.0/16
- **Allowed protocols and ports** tcp

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer, had to update the **Path**: / to something that always has a respons: /wp-login.php